# Display grand total as the sum of averages (custom subtotal)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, matrix, rdlc

I have SQL Server query, which returns the following data:
[image]

I want to display the data in RDLC 2008 Report using matrix format which should give the following result:
[image]

The Grand Total of Qty field should return 12 for January & 14 for February. 
I have tried many different methods one of which is by using the following expression in the matrix 'Qty' textbox :

```
=IIF(InScope("RowGroup_Category")
 ,IIF(InScope("RowGroup_SubCategory")
          ,Fields!Qty.Value
      ,Code.GetAverageMemberCount(Cint(Avg(Fields!Qty.Value)))
      )
     ,Code.TotalMemberCount
)
```

The above functions are written in Report Properties Code as below:

```
Public Dim TotalMemberCount As Integer = 0

Function GetAverageMemberCount(ByVal AverageMemberCount As Integer) As Integer
TotalMemberCount = TotalMemberCount + AverageMemberCount
    Return AverageMemberCount
End Function
```

I have also tried `RunningValue(Fields!Qty.Value,Sum,"RowGroup_Category")` and many such functions but I am unable to get the exact results. any help would be appreciated.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this into a new column as a test:

```
    RunningValue(Avg(Fields!MemberCount.Value,"RowGroup_Category"),SUM,Nothing)
```

If the value is correct you should be able to change SUM into MAX when setting this expression in the grand total field.

You can refer to the total like code.TotalMemberCount instead of using a get function
but i don't think you need this function in this case.

Check [the following blog](http://geekswithblogs.net/ryanc/archive/2008/06/26/123410.aspx) for a simular variable referencing situation

Comment: no the row group data is not limited to only 2 .. i have posted  sample data .. there can be n rows in row groups and subgroups .. likewise for column groups .. so i cannot think anything static but any function that i apply has to be dynamic

Comment: Do you know RunningValue Function ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159136(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: Dear Jacob, i have tried many of the functions available including RunningValue but they do not work. I have given the sample resultset from database and its matrix output and I need to get the total of subtotals and the subtotal of the field is the average of that group. so in a sense i need the sum of averages..

Comment: or in a sense lets say i need the sum of distinct values 19 + 110 what you suggested earlier 'RunningValue(Avg(Fields!MemberCount.Value,"RowGroup_Category"),SUM,Nothing)' will not work as it wont allow Avg function in Running value function .. the expression should only be the field name say 'Fields!MemberCount.Value'

Comment: You can add an calculated field  with avg, and do the sum of that in a running value i believe, other solution i can think of, is to create an array variable in the code, and store all the averages in it.

Comment: the RunningValue() function you specified in example is not working. It won;t accept and an Avg function as parameter

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could find that worked for me to solve this is to calculate the averages in a different dataset and use lookup functions to fill the grand total from there.

In your case I would add a key column in your original dataset:

```
select Category + '|' + Month as key, Category, SubCategory, Month, Qty, Amt 
from YourTable
```

Create another dataset using:

```
select Category + '|' + Month as key, Category, Month, avg(Qty)
from YourTable
group by Category, Month
```

Add the second result as DataSet2 to the report. (In Visual Studio in the Report Data pane right click on DataSets.)

Add to the Report Properties -> Code section the following:

```
Function SumArray(varArray as array) as Decimal
     Dim retVal As Decimal = 0
     For Each item As Decimal In varArray 
         retVal = retVal + item
     Next
     Return retVal
End Function
```

Finally in the report use the following expression for Grand Total under Qty:

```
=code.SumArray(Lookupset(Fields!key.Value, Fields!key.Value, Fields!qty.Value, "DataSet2"))
```

P.S.: Make sure that the second dataset is also filled by your code the same way the original was.